# Why Geekbench result is three times lower than another result for the same model

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, benchmark

My MacBook Air (13 inch, mid 2012) started to be very sluggish recently: every action occurs after a visible delay (starting app, loading youtube in a browser, startup, etc). Besides, Newer Tech battery that I installed in mid-December died (macOS thinks I don't have a battery at all).

I ran Geekbench 4 on my machine after closing other apps (I actually left Dropbox and pcloud running, but closed Safari and itunes).
It turned out that my CPU score in Geekbench 4 is three times less than reported by another user with exactly same machine):

https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/compare/6882608?baseline=6473068

The only difference I can see is that I use macOS 10.13.3 while another user uses macOS 10.13.2.
Can poor performance of my MacBook be attributed only to the difference in macOS version?

Comment: you could run the Activity monitor and see if some process is using a lot of cpu time.

Comment: This is not necessarily an answer, but have you checked Activity Monitor to make sure there isn't another process that is consuming your CPU power? If you sort by CPU usage, you'll be able to see if there is something using enough power to skew the test results.

Comment: Yes, I've checked Activity monitor. It says that the processor is ~80-90% idle. Under longer observation, it seems that kernel_task and WindowServer kick in from time to time and take 20-40 % of CPU.

Comment: @jmh, I've commented on this below Artiste212 answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the battery somehow got disconnected: without a working battery my laptop was very slow.

After opening the laptop and reconnecting the battery, it works fine again.

Answer (score 2):

No, minor differences in macOS versions do not have an impact of that magnitude on benchmark scores.

If you have battery and thermal problems with the laptop, you might be experiencing performance throttling in order to limit power consumption.